# Как исправить ошибку отсутствия модуля в python?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10, n_jobs=-1, weights='distance').fit(X, Y)
scores = cross_val_score(knn, X, Y, cv=LeaveOneOut(len(X)))

print(scores.mean())
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему возникает такая ошибка: `from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'`

Модуль не найден, как такое может быть? Как можно исправить?

Comment: Ибо такой подбиблиотеки нет. Наверное вам нужен `from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score` .

Comment: да, так сработало. Спасибо!